# How to send SMS to multiple numbers using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a Bulk SMS service application for our university
the following file is the form for sending SMS.

**index.php**

```
<body>
<?php
//Code using curl

//Change your configurations here.
//---------------------------------
$username="XYZ";
$api_password="4dlfed5scaweod1";
$sender="test";
$domain="your_domain";
$priority="1";// 1-Normal,2-Priority,3-Marketing
$method="POST";
//---------------------------------

if(isset($_REQUEST['send']))
    {

        $mobile=$_REQUEST['mobile'];

        $message=$_REQUEST['message'];

        $username=urlencode($username);
        $api_password=urlencode($api_password);
        $sender=urlencode($sender);
        $message=urlencode($message);

        $parameters="username=$username&api_password=$api_password&sender=$sender&to=$mobile&message=$message&priority=$priority";

        $url="http://bulksms.gateway4sms.com/pushsms.php";

        $ch = curl_init($url);

        if($method=="POST")
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$parameters);
        }
        else
        {
            $get_url=$url."?".$parameters;

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $get_url);
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
        $return_val = curl_exec($ch);


        if($return_val=="")
        echo "Process Failed, Please check domain, username and password.";
        else
            echo "$return_val";

        }
?>
<article>
<h1>SMS APPLICATION</h1>
<form name="f1" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="name"> Name:</label>
            <input type="text" size="40" id="name" />
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="year">To the Students of:</label>
            <select id="year">
                <option>1st year</option>
                <option>2nd year</option>
                <option>3rd year</option>
                <option>4th year</option>
            </select>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea cols="50" rows="5" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
        </li>
    </ul>


     <p>
            <button type="submit" class="action" name="send">Send Message</button>
            <button type="reset" class="right">Reset</button>
        </p>
    </form>
    </article>
    <footer>
    </footer>
```

The user should be able to send to the group of Students from the list.
The phone numbers are stored in the database in the table named 'phonebook'

**Phonebook TABLE**

```
id  NAME          number       year
1   subh       90199492070     1st year
2   saefh      90199493050     2nd year
3   sawd       90199390450     1st year
4   suwd       90199543450     4th year
```

How do i retrieve the numbers to send the people from the database

Comment: What have you tried? Please research your question first! A google search, "PHP database" would turn up how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you haven't tried. I could give you ideas.

- Query your database and retrieve the results from phonebook table. (say the query will `SELECT name,number FROM phonebook`
- Grab those results [name and mobile number] in an array.
- Make use of a loop say a `for` loop and add your cURL code inside that.. such that

  `for($i=0;$i<count($results);$i++)
      {
      //.... your cURL code
      }`

Comment: thank you very much for your help...
How to know which option is selected from the list using PHP i.e
     <select id="year">
                <option>1st year</option>
                <option>2nd year</option>
                <option>3rd year</option>
                <option>4th year</option>
     </select>

Comment: Just use this `echo $_POST['year'];` , also change your `<select id="year">` to `<select name="year">`